# Analytical algorithm to obtain solution to convex optimization problem.

Tags: convergence-divergence, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Assume a vector $\vec{P}$ with N elements $\in \mathbb{R}^+$ and constants $T_P$ and $\epsilon$. The vector $\vec{P}$ is arranged in a column $(N\times 1)$.

Consider the problem:
$$
 \begin{aligned}
 &{\text{minimize}}
 & & \sum_{k \in \mathcal{K}} \frac{1}{P_{k}^2} \\
 & \text{subject to}
 & & \vec{P}^H\vec{P} \le T_P \\
 &&& \vec{Z}^H\vec{Z} \le \epsilon 
 \end{aligned}
$$
where $\mathcal{K}$ is a subset of the set $\{0, 1, ... N-1\}$, and $\vec{Z} = W\vec{P}$ where $W$ is a $L \times N$ matrix (L > N).

I have converted it into a convex problem (SDP) given below:

$$
\begin{aligned}
 &{\text{minimize}}
 & & ||\vec{t}|| \\
 & \text{subject to}
 & & \begin{bmatrix}
 diag(\vec{P}_{\mathcal{K}}) & I \\
 I & diag(\vec{t})
 \end{bmatrix} \succ 0\\
 &&& \vec{P}^H\vec{P} \le T_P \\
 &&& \vec{Z}^H\vec{Z} \le \epsilon 
 \end{aligned}
$$

I have solved the above in cvx and obtained optimal values of P. Now I need to obtain analytical solutions of this or of the original problem. Is there any iterative algorithm to do the same? If so, how does it converge?

Comment: I don't know what you mean here. It's almost certain that there is no analytical solution to this problem. And CVX uses a standard iterative algorithm to solve it. So you already have what you've asked for.

Comment: I see. Thank you for clearing it.